# variable assignment in tensorflow v2

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am converting my code to Tensorflow v2 and I keep getting the following error:

> AssertionError: Called a function referencing variables which have been deleted. This likely means that function-local variables were created and not referenced elsewhere in the program. This is generally a mistake; consider storing variables in an object attribute on first call.

Here is a minimal example that reproduces the error

```
import tensorflow as tf

class TEST:
    def __init__(self, a=1):
        self.a = tf.Variable(a)

    @tf.function
    def increment(self):
        self.a = self.a + 1
        return self.a

tst = TEST()
tst.increment()
```

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do:

```
self.a = self.a + 1
```

You are overwriting the reference in `self.a`, which was initially associated to the variable created above, with the result of that operation. You are *not* updating the value of the TensorFlow variable, only replacing the Python reference. That new tensor you are creating (the result of `self.a + 1`) does, in turn, use that variable in its computation. The problem is, the moment `self.a` is overwritten, the variable is forgotten, and cannot be used anymore. It's a bit of a chicken-egg thing, but `tf.function` considers that to be invalid. If you want to have the variable and assign it a new value, do something like this:

```
@tf.function
def increment(self):
    self.a.assign(self.a + 1)
    return self.a
```

Or just his:

```
@tf.function
def increment(self):
    self.a.assign_add(1)
    return self.a
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!